# Reproduce gnuplot's with boxes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gnuplot

Is there a way to reproduce the format of gnuplot's `with boxes` in matplotlib? The closest so far seems to be `.step`.

In Gnuplot:

```
import Gnuplot
gplt = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
data = Gnuplot.Data(zip(range(3), range(3)), with_="boxes")
gplt.plot(data)
```

In Pyplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.step(range(3), range(3))
```

produces (left for Gnuplot)

[image: gnuplot box drawing] 
[image: matplotlib steps]

How can the boxes be drawn to the x-axis each time in pyplot?

Comment: Bar chart with bars not filled and no space between bars?

Comment: @DavidG: Thank you. Might work. How do you compute the widths?

Comment: I guess it would be the spacing of your x values

Comment: @DavidG: exactly, I had wondered how to compute them in one line, but a loop works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a bar chart with no space between the bars and setting `fill=False`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(range(3), range(3), fill=False, width=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]